# navigation bar entire width spaced items evenly

Tags: css

I'm a bit new to css. I'm trying to make a horizontal navigation bar with only 3 text items for mobile device viewing. I have width set to 100% and each section width set to 32% (I tried 33% but it would place the 3rd item on a new line.) It looks ok as it is, but when I hover (or click on using a mobile device) the background color changes and you can see the margins.

```
ul.nav {
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#62564A;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: sans-serif; 
}

.nav li { 
        display:inline;
    }

.nav a {
    width:33%;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-bottom:13px;
    padding-top:12px;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}

.nav a:hover { 
    background:#A26A42;
    border:none;
    width:32%
}

ul.nav li:first-child a{
    border:none;
}
ul.nav li:last-child a {
    border:none;
}
```

End of CSS

```
<ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Legend</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="map_canvas" style="position:absolute;left:0;right:0;"></div>
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd rework your CSS like this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/HBXku/)**.

**CSS**

```
ul.nav {
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    background-color:#62564A;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: sans-serif; 
}
.nav li { 
    display:inline-block;
    width:33%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.nav a {
    text-align:center;
    padding:12px 0 13px 0;
    margin:0;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    display:block;
}
.nav a:hover { 
    background:#A26A42;
    border:none;
}

ul.nav li:first-child a{
    border:none;
}
ul.nav li:last-child a {
    border:none;
}​
```

Comment: Hi thanks this worked. I didn't realize I need to put the list items on one line like so:<li><a href="#">Search</a></li><li><a href="#">Legend</a></li><li><a href="#">Info</a></li>  When I tried to put each one on a separate line "Info" goes on a second line using jfiddle

Comment: That's a trick for eliminating any white space that can creep in and cause mysterious gaps.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to highlight on/off each nav li section when it is tapped? The hover works fine if you tap it once (the background changes) but it does not revert back to the original background when you tap it again. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; } // This reset should go at the top of your CSS (if you don't have one already)

.nav li {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width: 33%;
}
.nav li a {
    display:block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/duaa6/

Comment: Thank you this worked. However now I get a small white space between the navbar and my next div (which is a map canvas). Is there a way to get rid of this?

Comment: @Andrew Not sure w/o seeing the rest of the code, but I updated my fiddle to include a subsequent div (which has no space) http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/duaa6/

Answer (score 0):

On "hover" you make the menu items narrower than normal. Plus you remove ther border which will narrow it even more. Also, It looks like you are using a 1px border left and right for spacing. If this is the case use margin instead. Use jsfiddle to practice.

Try this:

```
    ul.nav {
        width:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        list-style:none;
        text-align:center;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    .nav li {
        display:inline;
    }

    .nav a {
        width:32%;
        text-align:center;
        display:inline-block;
        padding-bottom:13px;
        padding-top:12px;
        margin-left: 1px;
        background: #62564A;            
    }

    .nav a:hover {
        background:#A26A42;
    }

    ul.nav li:first-child a{
        margin-left: 0;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mVv75/4/